# Debugging "Hello world" sample plug-in : What about my breakpoint ...?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, eclipse

i'm trying to understand the **Eclipse/Pydev/Qgis** configuration :
i installed Eclipse (on a win7 pc) + Pydev and Remote Debug and the "hello world" example plugin in Qgis.

I open **HelloWorld.py**  in Eclipse and set a breakpoint at the beginning of the class definition. I start the debug server.

When i start Remote Debug in QGIS i get a "**debuggin connection activated**" message. all seems to be running ok ...

But when i run the Hello World plug-in in Qgis **the execution is not stopped at breakpoint** as expected and the message box "Hello World" pops up on the screen ...

What could i be missing ?

Comment: same as you, did you get it work ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set in remote debug plugin the pysrc path of the current pydevd installation in your eclipse => look for path "paysrc". Beware! you can have more than one pydevd_ installation, so choose the latest one.
And remember to update the path set in remote plugin every time you update pydevd in eclipse.
This is exactly the same stuffs to do also if pydevd is that shoipped with PyCharm (not community).

Comment: thanks for your interest. That's I dit : I am on MacOS so I set the pydev Path in the plugin debugger  : `/Users/R/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_6.0.0.201709191431/pysrc` and as it wrote in the question "When i start Remote Debug in QGIS i get a "debuggin connection activated" message. all seems to be running ok ...". But this get me on the way to try something and now it's work fine :) look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's quite upsetting to see a beautiful blue " debuggin connection activated" message when it's not...

[edit] remove wrong answer.

In my case (qgis 2.18.7) I should start the debug server, start or restart Qgis and on the welcome page run the debugger plugin, then I can see the MainTread in Pydev :
[image]